# Saber si archivo esta en uso (.exe)

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para actualizar mi sistema, lo descargo en el %temp% luego aplico:

```
File.Copy(LocalFolderTemp + fileNameFTP, fileNameFTP,true);
```

Pero cuando el archivo esta en uso EXE's no lanza ningun aviso que no se pudo copiar, simplemente lo pasa.
Estos usado esto para saber si esta en uso:

```
public static bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
    {
        FileStream stream = null;
        try
        {
            stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            //the file is unavailable because it is:
            //still being written to
            //or being processed by another thread
            //or does not exist (has already been processed)
            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.Close();
        }
        //file is not locked
        return false;
    }
```

El cual funciona con DOC, XLS..Etc, pero con los exe no pasa nada, ¿que se puede hacer?
Cuando el archivo esta cerrado funciona muy bien.

Comment: te sugiero otro enfoque que quizas te sirva, y es que en vez de buscar fisicamente si el fichero esta abierto, busca en memoria el proceso asociado a ese .EXE, creo que puede ser mas facil y mas fiable. Un saludo.

Comment: Tienes razón, encontré la solución: bool isRunning = Process.GetProcessesByName("Uranus")
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainModule.FileName.StartsWith(@"C:\Temp\SUpdate\Uranus.exe")) != default(Process); ¿Esto mismo se puede aplicar a archivos TXT, DOC, XLS.. ó para esos casos se usa el bloque de código anterior?

Comment: Estás seguro que no genera una excepción File.Copy cuando el exe está en uso? Debería generar una excepción del tipo IOException

Comment: Pues no, le quito el Try, teniendo el EXE abierto y se pasa de largo.

Comment: La IOException, sólo me produce con los archivos DOC, XLS...Etc, pero con los EXE no.

Comment: yo para el resto de casos usaria el codigo anterior. los .exe son especiales porque se ejecutan en memoria, el resto de ficheros son almacenes de datos por decirlo de alguna manera.